# Material Angular: automatic scroll to invalid Input and open matstepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

I hope that someone can help ; my question is that if it's possible or if there is a module to scroll to invalid field and open the matstepper that contain this field.

i try to use ngxScrollToFirstInvalid but it's not opening the mat stepper.

for now i have this code :

```
scrollTo(el: Element): void {
    if(el) {
     el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
 }

 scrollToError(): void {
    const firstElementWithError = document.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
    this.scrollTo(firstElementWithError);
 }

 async scrollIfFormHasErrors(form: FormGroup): Promise <any> {
   await form.invalid;
   this.scrollToError();
 }
```

This is a solution that i found but i try to use it but it doesn't work.

Sorry for my bad English.

The question is if there is a function to found and open the mat-stepper that contain the first invalid field.

Thanks

Comment: @Chellappanவ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-2h2xas

Comment: Do you want to autofocus tthe input field, If the input field is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mat-stepper instance you can get the form status. Then we can navigate to invalid step programeticaly. First in order to get mat-stepper instance you have to place #stepper template varibale on mat-vertical-component like this:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [linear]="isLinear">
```

Now add ViewChild in your ts like this to get stepper instance:

```
@ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;
```

Finally you can check individual form status using stepControl property like this and navigate to invalid step by setting selectedIndex

```
 scrollToError(): void {
    const steps = this.myStepper._steps.toArray();
     for(let i = 0; i < steps.length -1; i++ ){
        if(!steps[i].stepControl.valid){
       this.myStepper.selectedIndex = i;  
       return ;
    }
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-xz8n8m)

Comment: Great thanks to you @Chellapan this is what i want ! i will try it tomorrow in my project !

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that, the question is in a different stepper

1. Move to the Step where the question is
2. Move to the question

Here is a snippet of my code

```
  navigateToField(field: string) {
    if (!field || field.length === 0 || !field.includes('.')) {
      return;
    }
    // split the field to get the section and the field
    const sectionId = field.split('.')[0];
    const matchingSection: ISection = this.sectionData[Number(sectionId) - 1];
    const matchingField = matchingSection.questions.find(ques => ques.fieldLabel.includes(field));

    if (matchingField) {

      // once you match the field, call the move function to jump to the right Section
      this.move(Number(sectionId) - 1);

      // now scroll into the field
      setTimeout(() => {
        const el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(`${matchingField.fieldId}`);
        if (el) {
          el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', inline: 'nearest', behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
      }, 250);
    }
  }
```

```
 // move to the Step
 move(index: number) {
    this._logger.info(`move(${index})`);
    this.leftNavStepper.selectedIndex = index;
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
  }
```